# How to create a clickable hyperlink in a QGIS form?

Tags: qgis, qt, hyperlink

I have a hyperlink field in my table. I wish I could go to those addresses without using actions. I want to go directly from the form by clicking on them as happens in a hyperlink. It is possible?

---

I want to load web explorer doing double-click in url.

[image: Example]

Comment: Go to as in, zoom to in QGIS? Load in a web browser?

Comment: Double-click and load in a web browser but without actions or eVis. For example, like Ctrl+click in PDF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the hyperlink functionality is available in a QGIS form as it only seems to display data from the attribute table.

There is somewhat of an alternative if speed is your essence:

1. Download and install the **Hotlink** plugin.
2. Set up an action for your layer by inserting your url into the *Action* textbox, then click the **Add to action list** button:

   ```
   http://www.ual.es/conocenos/img/UAL2007.pdf
   ```
3. Toggle the **Hotlink** plugin icon to enable it and simply click on a polygon. Your default web browser will load and automatically search for the url.

Hope this helps!

Comment: But i don't want to search it on Google. What i want is, for example: http://www.ual.es/conocenos/img/UAL2007.pdf I want to open my web browser and load this url. Is it possible to do it like an action??? And in this case, How to do it? Thanks

Comment: Hi @Peter, I've edited my post.